# Reading Google App Engine's datastore to a native app

Tags: google-app-engine

Does anyone know if it is possible to read from a Datastore on the app engine to a native app?

I am working my way through making a simple notes app that I can store online and use on my phone and tablet. I would prefer the phone interface be more than just a WebView instance or only used from the browser. I would also like a tablet optimized version as well.

I am comfortable programming android, and I am comfortable with web apps as well, so this is the last important piece before I can start putting it all together.

Has anyone done this before? Or, if it isn't possible, can someone send a link so I can further explore and find out what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can interface directly with the datastore using [remote_api](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html), but this is designed as an administrative interface, and shouldn't be used for access by end-users. The standard approach for what you're doing - on any webapp, regardless of platform - is to define an API that your application exposes for access to the data, and consume that API from your native app. If you're using Python, you may want to check out [ProtoRPC](http://code.google.com/p/google-protorpc/) (now included in the SDK) as an easy way to define APIs.